# Changing number of ticks in parallel coordinate d3 V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is a parallel coordinate with some sample data 
http://plnkr.co/edit/dCNuBsaDNBwr7CrAJUBe?p=preview

Here the numerical axis like column1 , column3 have small number of data so it looks ok. But in practice, I have a big data (something like 600 entries), so numerical ticks in axis become clustered , overlapped.

Is there a way so that it looks good. Like Setting the number of ticks in parallel coordinate. For instance, if I want to change the number of ticks in column1 of this example from 10 to 5.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
   stroke-opacity: .4;  
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-opacity: .7;
}

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: #fff;

  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  cursor: move;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>


var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scalePoint().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = {},
    dragging = {};


var line = d3.line(),
    //axis = d3.axisLeft(x),
    background,
    foreground,
    extents;


 var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "parcoords")
    .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
    .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var quant_p = function(v){return (parseFloat(v) == v) || (v == "")};     

d3.json("convertcsv.json", function(error, cars) {

    dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]);

    x.domain(dimensions);

    dimensions.forEach(function(d) {
    var vals = cars.map(function(p) {return p[d];});
    if (vals.every(quant_p)){ 
     y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { 
            return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0])

        console.log(y[d]);
      }
    else{
     vals.sort();           
      y[d] = d3.scalePoint()
              .domain(vals.filter(function(v, i) {return vals.indexOf(v) == i;}))
              .range([height, 0],1);
       }

  })


 extents = dimensions.map(function(p) { return [0,0]; });


  // Add grey background lines for context.
  background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
  foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);



  // Add a group element for each dimension.

  var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .subject(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
        .on("start", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = x(d);
          background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
          foreground.attr("d", path);
          dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
          x.domain(dimensions);
          g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
        })
        .on("end", function(d) {
          delete dragging[d];
          transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
          transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
          background
              .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
              .delay(500)
              .duration(0)
              .attr("visibility", null);
        }));


  // Add an axis and title.
   var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension");
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) {  d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]));})
      //text does not show up because previous line breaks somehow
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9) 
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        if(y[d].name == 'r'){
         // console.log(this);

        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [8,height]]).on("brush start", brushstart).on("brush", go_brush).on("brush", brush_parallel_chart).on("end", brush_end));
        }


      else if(y[d].name == 'n')
             d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [15,height]]).on("brush start", brushstart).on("brush", go_brush).on("brush", brush_parallel).on("end", brush_end_ordinal)); 


      })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);  
});  // closing

function position(d) {
  var v = dragging[d];
  return v == null ? x(d) : v;
}

function transition(g) {
  return g.transition().duration(500);
}

// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
  return line(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
}

function go_brush() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}


invertExtent = function(y) {
  return domain.filter(function(d, i) { return y === range[i]; });
};


function brushstart(selectionName) {
  foreground.style("display", "none")

  //console.log(selectionName);

  var dimensionsIndex = dimensions.indexOf(selectionName);

  //console.log(dimensionsIndex);

  extents[dimensionsIndex] = [0, 0];

  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
    return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
        if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
            return true;
        }
      return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
    }) ? null : "none";
  });
}



// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush_parallel_chart() { 

   for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){


        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
         //if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;

            extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);

    }

}

     foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
          return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
      }); 
}    


function brush_end(){



  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // Only transition after input.
  if (!d3.event.selection) return; // Ignore empty selections.


for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){

    if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {

  extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);

   extents[i][0] = Math.round( extents[i][0] * 10 ) / 10;
   extents[i][1] = Math.round( extents[i][1] * 10 ) / 10;



    d3.select(this).transition().call(d3.event.target.move, extents[i].map(y[dimensions[i]]));

     }

  }

}

//   brush for ordinal cases
function brush_parallel() {


for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){

        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {


       var  yScale = y[dimensions[i]];
       var selected =  yScale.domain().filter(function(d){
            // var s = d3.event.target.extent();
          var s = d3.event.selection;

      return (s[0] <= yScale(d)) && (yScale(d) <= s[1])

      });


var temp = selected.sort();
extents[i] = [temp[temp.length-1], temp[0]];


   }

}

foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
          //var p_new = (y[p].ticks)?d[p]:y[p](d[p]); 
          //return extents[i][1] <= p_new && p_new <= extents[i][0];
        return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
      });     
}




function brush_end_ordinal(){

  console.log("hhhhh");


  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // Only transition after input.

  if (!d3.event.selection) return; // Ignore empty selections.

  for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){

        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {


       var  yScale = y[dimensions[i]];
       var selected =  yScale.domain().filter(function(d){
      // var s = d3.event.target.extent();
      var s = d3.event.selection;

      return (s[0] <= yScale(d)) && (yScale(d) <= s[1])

      });

  var temp = selected.sort();
  extents[i] = [temp[temp.length-1], temp[0]];

if(selected.length >1)
d3.select(this).transition().call(d3.event.target.move, extents[i].map(y[dimensions[i]]));


     }  
 } 



}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [d3-axis.ticks()](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_ticks) or [d3-axis.tickValues([])](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickValues) to specify custom number of ticks/tick values.

For example, for **column1** using `tickValues` and **column3** using `ticks`:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension");
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .each(function(d) {  
    if(d === 'column1') {
      d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]).tickValues([.1, .2, .3, .5,.8])); 
    } else if(d === 'column3') {
      d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]).ticks(4)); 
    } else {
      d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d])); 
    }
    
})
```

A fork of your plunkr: [TickValues and ticks DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GTNA5qxjK6ymOwsnETJM?p=preview)

Hope this helps. Read the docs for more options.